# Lisp - if statements various actions

Tags: lisp

This is my lisp code.

```
 (DEFUN F (A B)
              (SETF C (* 4 A))
              (SETF D (* 2 (EXPT B 3)))
              (SETF RES (+ C D))
              (IF (AND (TYPEP A 'INTEGER) (TYPEP B 'INTEGER))
                  (list 'Final 'value '= res)
                '(YOUR INPUTS ARE NOT NUMBERS)))
```

For example, `(f 5 9)` works well.
But `(f 'w 'q)` doesn't work with the following error message:

> (ERROR TYPE-ERROR DATUM W EXPECTED-TYPE NUMBER FORMAT-CONTROL
>             ~@<`~s' is not of the expected type`~s'~:@> FORMAT-ARGUMENTS
>             (W NUMBER))
>     Error: `W' is not of the expected type`NUMBER'

I want to make if A,B is integer calculate 4A+2B^3.

Else if at least one is not an integer print error message.

I try to the code shown above.
But how can I make this error handling using if statements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you should use [`LET` or `LET*`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_let_l.htm) to define local variables.

```
(defun f (a b)
  (let* ((c (* 4 a))           ; You need LET* instead of LET because
         (d (* 2 (expt b 3)))  ; RES depends on the previous variables.
         (res (+ c d)))
    (if (and (typep a 'integer) (typep b 'integer))
        (list 'final 'value '= res)
        '(your inputs are not numbers))))
```

The actual problem is that you're doing the calculations before you check that the arguments are integers. You should move the calculation inside the `IF`.

```
(defun f (a b)
  (if (and (integerp a) (integerp b))
      (let* ((c (* 4 a))
             (d (* 2 (expt b 3)))
             (res (+ c d)))
        (list 'final 'value '= res))
      '(your inputs are not numbers)))
```

Returning lists like that is kind of strange. If you intend them as output for the user, you should instead print the messages and return the actual result.

```
(defun f (a b)
  (if (and (integerp a) (integerp b))
      (let ((result (+ (* 4 a)
                       (* 2 (expt b 3)))))
        (format t "Final value = ~a~%" result)
        result)                                      ; Return RESULT or
      (format t "Your inputs are not integers.~%"))) ; NIL from FORMAT.
```

In most cases you should signal an error if the arguments are not correct type. Printing output from a function that does the calculation is usually a bad idea.

```
(defun f (a b)
  (check-type a integer "an integer")
  (check-type b integer "an integer")
  (+ (* 4 a)
     (* 2 (expt b 3))))

(defun main (a b)
  (handler-case
      (format t "Final value = ~a~%" (f a b))
    ;; CHECK-TYPE signals a TYPE-ERROR if the type is not correct.
    (type-error () (warn "Your inputs are not integers."))))

(main 12 1)
; Final value = 50
;=> NIL
(main 12 'x)
; WARNING: Your inputs are not integers.
;=> NIL
```

Common Lisp condition system also allows you to use restarts to fix errors. `CHECK-TYPE` establishes a restart named `STORE-VALUE`, which you can invoke to supply a correct value for the place. In this case it probably doesn't make sense, but you could do something like use `1` as a default.

```
(defun main (a b)
  (handler-bind ((type-error (lambda (e)
                               (store-value 1 e))))
    (format t "Final value = ~a~%" (f a b))))

(main 12 1)
; Final value = 50
;=> NIL
(main 12 'x)
; Final value = 50
;=> NIL
```

Notice that conditions/error handlers do add some overhead, so for performance critical functions you might not want to use them and instead check your arguments before calling the function.

```
(declaim (ftype (function (integer integer) integer) f))
(defun f (a b)
  (declare (optimize (speed 3) (safety 0) (debug 0)))
  (+ (* 4 a)
     (* 2 (expt b 3))))

(defun main (a b)
  (if (and (integerp a)
           (integerp b))
      (format t "Final value = ~a~%" (f a b))
      (warn "Your inputs are not integers.")))
```

Comment: From the beginner's point of view, there was a lot of help. Based on your precious materials I will more grow. Thank you.